# Neural network Dataset

Tags: dataset, machine-learning, neural-network, weka

I have been working on the neural network for that i need to train a data set in weka 
but i dont have any data set to implement on weka can anyone help me in that 
here is my paper in which im implementing

http://www.lcc.uma.es/~lfranco/A25-Gomez+Franco+09.pdf

Comment: and the exact question/problem is??

Comment: the problem is I need data set to whom i could implement on weka. Im unable to find that online, if anyone could help me that

Comment: ah ok, got it. I don't think this is the place to ask for a dataset, though. unfortunately I don't know the topic well enough to be sure the following question is meaningful: can't you generate and prepare this dataset by yourself?

Comment: seriously dont have any idea how to do that pls if anyone could do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datasets are simple to create. All you need is to think of a scenario. For example, in a school, students would need to score 75 or higher in physical fitness test but this would vary according to weight and height. So your attributes in the table would be:

Weight - Height - Marks - Pass/Fail

Pass/Fail would be your Neural Net's label.